# Populate an ExpandableListView from XML file - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, expandablelistview

In my Android application I've got an Activity containing an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

The items it will contain should be extracted from an `XML` file that the application will query to a Server when it starts (suppose the size of the file is not an issue).

The user should then be able to make modifications to the content of the `XML` file by adding, removing, editing items from the `ExpandableListView` with functionalities provided by the application. Eventually the application will send back the modified `XML` file to the Server.

For better understanding this mockup should explain what I'm trying to implement:

[image]

I'd like to know:

> how can I populate dynamically in `Java` the area highlighted in red
>   given the `XML` file?

**SAMPLE XML FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Category value="Animals">
    <entry>Cat</entry>
    <entry>Dog</entry>
    <entry>Elephant</entry>
</Category>
<Category value="Objects">
    <entry>Aeroplane</entry>
    <entry>Ball</entry>
    <entry>Closet</entry>
</Category>
```

---

**ADDED DEBUG PART**

I've tried to implement the solution proposed in the answer by @Luksprog but am facing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when running the following code:

*Code:*

```
//gets the View from the Layout file
myCustomExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById( R.id.myCustomExpandableListView );
//creates the array list that will contain all labels
ArrayList<Category> labelsInTaxonomy = new ArrayList<Category>();
//fills it with a private method that parses the XML and fills the array list
this.loadTaxonomyFromXml( labelsInTaxonomy );
//creates the custom expandable list adapter
CustomExpandable labelTaxonomyAdapter = new CustomExpandable( this, labelsInTaxonomy );
//sets the adapter
myCustomExpandableListView.setAdapter( labelTaxonomyAdapter );
```

*Error:*

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.DVA_HLUI/com.DVA_HLUI.DVA_HLUIManageTaxonomyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at com.DVA_HLUI.DVA_HLUIManageTaxonomyActivity.onCreate(DVA_HLUIManageTaxonomyActivity.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
```

Note that

`com.DVA_HLUI.DVA_HLUIManageTaxonomyActivity.onCreate(DVA_HLUIManageTaxonomyActivity.java:80)`

corresponds to this line of the code

`myCustomExpandableListView.setAdapter( labelTaxonomyAdapter );`

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How big is that xml that comes from the server?

Comment: @Luksprog - for the moment `XML` file size is not an issue, suppose it has just a few entries as in the sample code. Can I know why you asked?

Comment: If size isn't a issue then it's pretty simple. Get the xml from the server->build a structure to replicate the xml-> show it to the user in the list->user modifies that structure->parse the modified structure in a valid xml->send it to the server. If the size of the xml is to big you can't do the above as you'll probably run out of memory.

Comment: @Luksprog - yeah I know, but in case size becomes to big I was thinking to build a local database and some policies for sending only the modifications that have occurred in the local DB to the server and vice-versa. WHat do you think about this solution?

Comment: @Luksprog - Anyway, could you please explain more in details the solution you proposed? `build a structure to replicate the xml` is ok, but how to do this `show it to the user in the list`?

Comment: @Luksprog - I've implemented your solution but it's giving me some problem, can you please help me further?Thks in advance!

Comment: At that line the `myCustomExpandableListView` is probably `null`. Have you tested to see this? See if you have an `ExpandableListView` with that id in the layout(and that you set the content view before searching for it) also clean the project with menu Project ->Clean and try again.

Comment: @Luksprog - I tried to call some methods for debugging (such as `labelTaxonomyAdapter.getChildrenCount(0)` to see if it returned the correct number) and it seems working. The error is given only when the `setAdapter` method is called.

Comment: Your `ExpandableListView` reference is `null`. See why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a custom class like this:

```
class Category {

    private ArrayList<String> mEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String mCaTegoryName;

    public void addEntry(String entry) {
        mEntries.add(entry);
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        mCaTegoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getEntries() {
        return mEntries;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return mCaTegoryName;
    }
}
```

as a data structure and use the `ArrayList<Category>` that will result from parsing the xml in a custom adapter:

```
class CustomExpandable extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Category> mItems;

    public CustomExpandable(Context context, ArrayList<Category> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mItems.get(groupPosition).getEntries().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // implement the child view row
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mItems.get(groupPosition).getEntries().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mItems.get(groupPosition).getCategoryName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // implement the group View
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, it seems quite straightforward, just a doubt before I try it: which of the method stubs should I fill in?

Comment: @Matteo If you extend `BaseExpandableListAdapter` like I did you have to implement all the methods as all are required to be implemented. If you extend other adapters you should at least extend the methods that return the number of groups/children and the actual data for the groups/children to return the proper data.

Comment: Thks so much for the suggestions and clear explanation!I'll try it right now and give you feedback ASAP! ;D cheers...

Comment: I've implemented your solution but it's giving me some problem, can you please help me further?Thks in advance!