# expandable list view with xml entries

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, expandablelistview, multilingual

i want to display an expandable list view in android that contains constant strings defined in a XML file in the resources 
my app should support multiple languages so its the cleanest way to keep all strings together

i know its possible in normal listView where i can use the property

```
android:entries="@array/stringarray"
```

but when i  use it with expandable list it gives me an exception that i should use expandable list adapter instead of list adapter 
even know that i am not using any adapters "i think its implicit"

so obliviously "entries" is usable with expandable lists but cant find a way to make it work

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate an ExpandableListView from XML file - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772887/populate-an-expandablelistview-from-xml-file-android)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the easiest solution is to create an Expandable list adapter object and bind it to the expandable list object. When you add all the members of string array to the adapter elements, the expandable list will be modified accordingly.
Look at the [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) constructors to find out how to implement the idea mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for your reply but iam already aware of this technique but it seems like over killing since all i need is a static expander with the contents defined in XML ... and it should be possible since the SDK guys provided the property "entries" with the expandable list